# Neo4J optimize path generation query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

*How to make the query below work seconds instead of minutes?*

I'm new to graph databases. Am I right if I say that node indexing won't help to speed up my query? As I understand, indexes helps to find start point of traversal, not for traversing itself.

*May relationship indexing be helpful in my case?*

### Query

I have 2,500 nodes of type `COLUMN` and 52,000 relationships between nodes.

The query below is too slow, I even don't know how slow is it. It takes more than 5 minutes, than I get `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`.

### Query

```
MATCH path = (start:PERSON)-[r:MET_REL*2..5]->(person:PERSON) 
WHERE start.ID = '385' 
WITH path UNWIND NODES(path) AS col
WITH path, 
COLLECT(DISTINCT col.COUNTRY_ID) as distinctCountries
WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

### P.S.

Moreover, I want to do `[r:MET_REL*2..25]` instead of `[r:MET_REL*2..5]`

Comment: Sometimes queries aren't actually doing what you think they're doing, but it's hard for us to tell without a verbal description of your requirements. Can you explain the purpose of the query, what you want it to be doing, and what the output is supposed to be?

Comment: The problem is that the amount of data for the described model very high. I added specified the number of nodes and 52,000 random relationships between them. The number of paths of length equal to 4 on this model - 3847930. If the length is equal to 5, their number will grow very strongly. Like and search time. What to say about the length of the path 25? And as @InverseFalcon said you need to give more explanation of your original problem - maybe it will be necessary to change the data model.

Comment: can you share the query plan for this query? Best via prefixing it with `PROFILE`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an index/constraint on `:PERSON(ID)`

Please try this:

```
MATCH path = (start:PERSON)-[:MET_REL*2..5]->(person:PERSON) 
WHERE start.ID = '385' 
WITH path, reduce(a=[], n in nodes(path) | case when n.COUNTRY_ID IN a then a else a + [n.COUNTRY_ID] end) as countries
WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

With [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) there is an apoc.coll.toSet function that you could use on the countries.